# Accessing a variable from a different code-behind class

Tags: c#, asp.net

EDIT: made variables not-static.

I have a variable in code-behind class and want to access it from another.

Here's the C# code for the "Signup" page:

```cs
public partial class Webform_Signup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string user;
    public string User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set { user = value; }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request["submit"] != null)
        {
            user = HttpContext.Current.Request["user"];
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for another code-behind class in an .aspx class "Login":

```cs
public partial class Webform_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string loguser = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(HttpContext.Current.Request["logsubmit"] != null)
        {
            loguser = HttpContext.Current.Request["loguser"];
            if (loguser == Webform_signup.User)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Start");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to access `Webform_signup.user`, it displays an error saying:

> The name Webform_Signup does not exist in the current context.

Anyone has an idea of how to fix it?

Comment: That's what session state is for.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just variable naming?  The `private` field is named "user", but the `public` one is "User".  Besides the concern that they are both `static` (and probably should not be), you might consider dropping the private implementation and just inline it, such as `public static string User {get; set;}`

Comment: @SeanSkelly Storing user details in a static variable should never be recommended. It's a security flaw waiting to be exploited.

Comment: @mason Agreed.  I stated it "probably should not be" `static`.  Perhaps I was too polite/passive and should have dropped the "probably".  I was trying to focus on the user/User distinction, which I felt was a clue to the underlying problem OP was asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dirt simplest way (and probably not the best way) is to just stick it in a session variable and read it from there instead.

```
public partial class Webform_Signup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string user;
    public string User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set { user = value; }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request["submit"] != null)
        {
            user = HttpContext.Current.Request["user"];
            HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = user; //Save to session
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
}

public partial class Webform_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string loguser = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request["logsubmit"] != null)
        {
            loguser = HttpContext.Current.Request["loguser"];
            var user = HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]; //Read from session
            if (loguser == user)  
            {
                Response.Redirect("Start");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming of course that you have [session state enabled](https://discuss.workflowgen.com/t/how-to-enable-session-state-in-the-webforms-application/229).

Comment: Will look into that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind lifecycles. You're ignoring them, and the results would be disastrous in this case.

Any time you declare a variable as static, there will only be one instance of that variable in your application. That means no matter what user is using your app, the Webform_Signup.User field will be shared. That could result in users accessing other users' information! That's really, really bad.

Also, page classes should not be referring to other page classes. A page only exists when a user is accessing that page.

If you want to login a user, then perhaps you should research [Forms Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs). Or better yet, learn a modern framework like ASP.NET Core MVC instead of Web Forms, which is a deadend platform.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, this isn't some big project, i's just for school. What im trying to do is have a user sign in, and then be directed to a log in page. I need to check if the username and password he enters in the log in page is the same as what he entered in the signup page. Thanks for helping anyways.

Comment: @YuvalMoreno Then you're going about it the wrong way. This often happens when you try to roll your own authentication framework. I understand it's for school, but you might as well learn the right way now rather than learning the wrong way and then not know how to do it properly when you start your career. And if your school is requiring you to use Web Forms - you might want to rethink your education choices. Why learn a framework that's a deadend?

Comment: Idk man i'm in 10th grade, and this is what they want us to do. This isn't supposed to be something big or anything - it's just so i understand these concepts. Do you have any idead of how would i do it using webforms anyways?

Comment: @YuvalMoreno I already mentioned using Forms Authentication. If you want to try your own, but do it properly, then you need to one way hash the password and salt it when you receive it, then stored the hashed + salted value in a secure location (such as a database, perhaps a .json file in your App_Data folder if it's just for school and you have no DB). Then when the user comes back by to login later, you'd rehash and resalt the provided password. Compare that value with the value you stored when they signed up. If they match, then they provided the correct info.

Comment: @YuvalMoreno Solving this problem correctly is easier than what you're doing.  Don't roll your own, just use an existing effective and secure solution.  If you're doing this so that you understand the concepts then *doing it incorrectly won't teach you the concepts* because you'll be doing it wrong, and just learning bad habits.  If your teachers are any good, they would grade your solution poorly for exactly that reason.

Comment: I appriciate the efforts, but like I said, this isn't supposed to be anything big. The data isn't supposed to be stored when I close the application, and it doesn't need to be secured in any way. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @YuvalMoreno Sounds like you need to take a step back and ask yourself why you're practicing writing a login screen when you don't care about making it secure anything.  That's literally the purpose of a login screen.  If you don't want the content secured, then just *don't have a login process*.  If your teacher is any good, they'd grade your solution poorly for being insecure and unreliable, if they're not, you don't want them teaching you in the first place.

Comment: Well, im practicing writing a login screen because that's what my (great) teacher told me to do. This is literally for practicing client to server communication, and nothing beyond that. I aprriciate your efforts, but making it secure isn't the point here.